# Error when setting margins programmatically on generated TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I generate textViews like this :

```
   TextView myView  = new TextView(this);
   myView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));
   linearLayout2.addView(myView);
```

When I change this code to this to set margins :

```
   TextView myView  = new TextView(this);
   myView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myString));
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
   params.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
   myView.setLayoutParams(params);
   linearLayout2.addView(myView);
```

I get this error :

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example./com.example.Activity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.setMargins(int, int, int,
>   int)' on a null object reference

How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: you should create new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) instead of getting them from the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is in line

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
```

`myView.getLayoutParams();` will return null because it is not still added in any view. you only need first add the view in linearLayout2 after that you can get LayoutParams from view.

Alternatively you can create your own layout params and assign those to your view. like this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParam params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 6):

you should create 
`new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`

instead of getting them from the view.

Answer (score 1):

you could start passing an instance of `LayoutParams`, when you add your `TextView`. E.g.

```
linearLayout2.addView(myView, new
       LinearLayout .LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```